# Unique readability of informal mathematical/logical English prose?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, formal-languages

I've always been bothered by the use of informal English commonplace in the metalanguage of logic or mathematics texts, which although efficient, is possibly ambiguous.

For some (make up your own if you want) informal and restricted (e.g. Stating P∧Q only as "P and Q" or or "The conjunction of P and Q" if preceded by another connective) language, can there be a unique parsing/readability theorem of it?

Comment: Mathematicians and logicians seemed to mastered language to express ideas uniquely. Not aware of a decent and practiced mathematician that has caused confusion because of a grammar ambiguity.

Comment: This isn't really a mathematical question and parsing and readability aren't really the problem. The important underlying question is considered very carefully by Tarski on his [seminal paper on the definability of truth](http://www.thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Course_Websites/Readings/Tarski%20-%20The%20Concept%20of%20Truth%20in%20Formalized%20Languages.pdf).

Comment: “informal and restricted” IMHO, these are incompatible. If a language has precise rules, it is formal. Languages are defined by grammars. Unique parsing corresponds to unambiguous grammars. In principle, it is possible to create a grammar for a formal language built from natural words and phrases like you want. This is studied in computer science. I suggest that you ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ .